# Jug -Failed to create server

Tags: r, api

I have run the below script to build a API from a RF model.
I receive the following message: "Serving the jug at http://127.0.0.1:8080
Error in startServer(host, port, app) : Failed to create server". In another posts a user had the same problem with the Shiny package, and it was recommended to install the updated package version. I downloaded the latest Jug version from Github (devtools::install_github("Bart6114/jug")), but this didn't solve the problem in my case. Does anyone know how to solve it?
Thanks

```
library(randomForest)
library(jug)
mpg_fit<-randomForest(mpg~disp+wt+hp, mtcars)
saveRDS(mpg_fit, "mpg_fit.Rdata")
pg_fit<-readRDS("mpg_fit.Rdata")
predict_mpg<-function(disp, wt, hp){
  new_data<-data.frame(disp=as.numeric(disp), 
                   wt=as.numeric(wt),
                   hp=as.numeric(hp))
 predict(mpg_fit, newdata = new_data)
}
jug() %>%
post("/mpg_api", decorate(predict_mpg)) %>%
simple_error_handler() %>%
serve_it()
```

Comment: `serve_it()` takes a port parameter. Try changing it to something besides 8080. There's a chance that you've already got something running on that port on your system (it's a very common port for local apps).

Comment: Thanks hrbrmstr. Can you help me with the code to change the port? Thanks

Comment: do `?serve_it`. You'll see it takes a `port` parameter that is pre-set to `8080`. Just add that parameter to the call and make it some other number (like `9183`).

Comment: Thanks, that overcame the problem. However when I get to the web page provided by the jug command I now get the error "No handler bound to path".

Comment: I'm not super familiar with `jug` so I wasn't sure what parameters to pass to the api as well